# Trying to create a drivers license exam program using methods

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a Java program that grades the written portion of a driver's license exam where the user needs to answer 15 out of 20 question correctly to pass. There should be a method that will allow the user to enter in their choices. Include input validation and only accept the letters A, B, C, or D.

There should also be a second method that will evaluate the student’s answers, display the number of questions answered correctly, whether the student passed or failed the exam, and populate another array that holds the question numbers answered incorrectly.

A third method will display the question numbers that were missed.

What I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DriverLicenseExam 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   // Arrays
   String[] correctAnswers = {"B", "D", "A", "A", "C", 
                              "A", "B", "A", "C", "D", 
                              "B", "C", "D", "A", "D", 
                              "C", "C", "B", "D", "A"};
   String[] userAnswers; 
   int[] missed = new int[correctAnswers.length];
   String[] answers = new String[20]; 
   String answer; 

   // User's input
   System.out.println("Enter your answers for the exam here: "); 
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
      {
         do
         {
            System.out.print((x+1) + ": "); 
            answer = input.nextLine(); 
         } 
         while (!isValidAnswer(answer)); 

         answers[x] = answer; 
      }

      //Process the user's answers
          userAnswers = new String[answers.length]; 

          for (int x = 0; x < answers.length; x++)
          {
             userAnswers[x] = answers[x]; 
          }


      //Results 
      int correctCount = totalCorrect();
      int incorrectCount = totalIncorrect();
      int missedCount = questionsMissed();

      //Outputting total correct
      System.out.println("Total Correct: " + correctCount); 

      //Outputting total incorrect
      System.out.println("Total Incorrect: " + incorrectCount);

      //Outputting missed questions
      System.out.println("Total missed: " + missed);
   }

   // Determines total correct answers
      public static int totalCorrect()
   {
      int correctCount = 0; 

          for (int x = 0; x < correctAnswers.length; x++)
          {
             if (userAnswers[x].equalsIgnoreCase(correctAnswers[x]))
             {
                correctCount++; 
             }
          }
          return correctCount;
   }

   // Determines total incorrect answers
   public static int totalIncorrect()
       {
          int incorrectCount = 0; 

          for (int x = 0; x < correctAnswers.length; x++)
          {
             if (!userAnswers[x].equalsIgnoreCase(correctAnswers[x]))
             {
                missedCount[incorrectCount] = x; 
                incorrectCount++; 
             }
          }
          return incorrectCount; 
       }

       // Determines total questions missed
       public int[] questionsMissed()
       {
          return missedCount; 
       }

       // Returns if user's answer is valid
       public static boolean isValidAnswer (String answer)
   {
      return "A".equalsIgnoreCase(answer) || 
         "B".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)
         || "C".equalsIgnoreCase(answer) || 
         "D".equalsIgnoreCase(answer); 
   }
}
```

Output:

```
DriverLicenseExam.java:48: error: non-static method questionsMissed() cannot be referenced from a static context
      int missedCount = questionsMissed();
                        ^
DriverLicenseExam.java:48: error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int
      int missedCount = questionsMissed();
                                       ^
DriverLicenseExam.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
          for (int x = 0; x < correctAnswers.length; x++)
                              ^
  symbol:   variable correctAnswers
  location: class DriverLicenseExam
DriverLicenseExam.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
             if (userAnswers[x].equalsIgnoreCase(correctAnswers[x]))
                                                 ^
  symbol:   variable correctAnswers
  location: class DriverLicenseExam
DriverLicenseExam.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
             if (userAnswers[x].equalsIgnoreCase(correctAnswers[x]))
                 ^
  symbol:   variable userAnswers
  location: class DriverLicenseExam
DriverLicenseExam.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
          for (int x = 0; x < correctAnswers.length; x++)
                              ^
  symbol:   variable correctAnswers
  location: class DriverLicenseExam
DriverLicenseExam.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
             if (!userAnswers[x].equalsIgnoreCase(correctAnswers[x]))
                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable correctAnswers
  location: class DriverLicenseExam
DriverLicenseExam.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
             if (!userAnswers[x].equalsIgnoreCase(correctAnswers[x]))
                  ^
  symbol:   variable userAnswers
  location: class DriverLicenseExam
DriverLicenseExam.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
                missed[incorrectCount] = x; 
                ^
  symbol:   variable missed
  location: class DriverLicenseExam
DriverLicenseExam.java:94: error: cannot find symbol
          return missedCount; 
                 ^
  symbol:   variable missedCount
  location: class DriverLicenseExam
10 errors
```

I am having trouble with these errors and don't understand how to fix it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: At the moment the scope of `correctAnswers` is limited to the `main` method (because that is where you declared it).  If you want to use it in other methods you needs to either declare it as a field **or** pass it as a parameter to the other methods.

Comment: Same problem for `userAnswers` as well.

Comment: Beyond what was said above, here's a general tip: when coding, don't just barge ahead and write 3-4 functions before running the code. By then, you've accumulated dozens of errors and it becomes frustrating to unwind all the problems. If you compile and run the code every time you change a few lines, I think you'll find that the problems become much more obvious and resolvable when you detect them immediately.

Answer (score 0):

There are few suggestion, I would like to give you:
 1. As ggorlen mentioned in the comment section, dont try to write bulky code at once and then test it. Keep testing your code as you write it.
 2. Use editor, there are many free JAVA editors available which will help you to debug or to identify the errors in the code.
 3. Please try to read some basic concepts like scoping, static keyword, return types.

One of the error that you have:

```
DriverLicenseExam.java:48: error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int
      int missedCount = questionsMissed();
```

because your method return an array and you are catching that into an int variable.

Answer (score 0):

Because your parameters are not global, I made some modifications, 
you can see that:

fix your three method:

```
    int[] missedCount = questionsMissed(missed);
    int correctCount = totalCorrect(correctAnswers,userAnswers);
    int incorrectCount = totalIncorrect(correctAnswers,userAnswers,missedCount);
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DriverLicenseExam
{
```

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Arrays
    String[] correctAnswers = {"B", "D", "A", "A", "C",
            "A", "B", "A", "C", "D",
            "B", "C", "D", "A", "D",
            "C", "C", "B", "D", "A"};
    String[] userAnswers;
    int[] missed = new int[correctAnswers.length];
    String[] answers = new String[20];
    String answer;

    // User's input
    System.out.println("Enter your answers for the exam here: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
    {
        do
        {
            System.out.print((x+1) + ": ");
            answer = input.nextLine();
        }
        while (!isValidAnswer(answer));

        answers[x] = answer;
    }

    //Process the user's answers
    userAnswers = new String[answers.length];

    for (int x = 0; x < answers.length; x++)
    {
        userAnswers[x] = answers[x];
    }



    int[] missedCount = questionsMissed(missed);

    //Results
    int correctCount = totalCorrect(correctAnswers,userAnswers);
    int incorrectCount = totalIncorrect(correctAnswers,userAnswers,missedCount);

    //Outputting total correct
    System.out.println("Total Correct: " + correctCount);

    //Outputting total incorrect
    System.out.println("Total Incorrect: " + incorrectCount);

    //Outputting missed questions
    System.out.println("Total missed: " + missed);
}

// Determines total correct answers
public static int totalCorrect(String[] correctAnswers,String[] userAnswers)
{
    int correctCount = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < correctAnswers.length; x++)
    {
        if (userAnswers[x].equalsIgnoreCase(correctAnswers[x]))
        {
            correctCount++;
        }
    }
    return correctCount;
}

// Determines total incorrect answers
public static int totalIncorrect(String[] correctAnswers,String[] userAnswers,int[] missedCount)
{
    int incorrectCount = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < correctAnswers.length; x++)
    {
        if (!userAnswers[x].equalsIgnoreCase(correctAnswers[x]))
        {
            missedCount[incorrectCount] = x;
            incorrectCount++;
        }
    }
    return incorrectCount;
}

// Determines total questions missed
public static int[] questionsMissed(int[] missedCount)
{
    return missedCount;
}

// Returns if user's answer is valid
public static boolean isValidAnswer (String answer)
{
    return "A".equalsIgnoreCase(answer) ||
            "B".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)
            || "C".equalsIgnoreCase(answer) ||
            "D".equalsIgnoreCase(answer);
}
}

Comment: A good answer isn't just code, but includes some kind of explanation about what you did and why. This is worth a read, too: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)